# Proxy環境下でのionic環境構築について

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, npm

ionicを使ってアプリを作ろうとしているのですが、
proxy環境下で

```
ionic start myapp
```

のコマンドを実行するとエラーが発生してしまいます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

エラーの内容から推測すると、proxyの設定でエラーが出ているのかと思うのですが、
.npmrcにも以下のように設定を追加済みです。

```
proxy=http://XXXXXXX:8080/
https-proxy=http://XXXXXXX:8080/
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
strict-ssl=false
```

npmを使って、gulpなど他のツールなどは問題無くインストールでき、
gitなどのツールに関してもproxy設定済みのため、特に問題なく使用できています。

作業を行っているPC環境は以下のとおりです。

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.16
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.3
ios-deploy version: 1.8.6 
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v4.4.7
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3.1 Build version 7D1014
```

こちら、どういった原因が考えられますでしょうか？

Comment: エラーメッセージがスクリーンショットですと、検索に引っかからず、他に困っている人の役に立たないQ&Aになりがちです。端末の文字は選択できると思いますので、コピペして下さると助かります。

Answer (score 1):

Requesモジュールがエラーを出していますね。

> The following environment variables are respected by request:
>
> ```sh
> HTTP_PROXY / http_proxy
> HTTPS_PROXY / https_proxy
> NO_PROXY / no_proxy
> ```
>
> [RequesのREADME](https://github.com/request/request#proxies)

という事ですから、これらの環境変数を設定すればよいようですが、現状はどうでしょう。

```sh
echo "$HTTP_PROXY, $http_proxy, $HTTPS_PROXY, $https_proxy, $NO_PROXY, $no_proxy"
```

などとして確認して見てください。

---

追記:

#### `http_proxy`などの環境変数に関して

`.npmrc`の設定はnpmにのみ有効です。
それに対し、`http_proxy`などの環境変数は多くのツールが参照し、これの設定に従います。
ionic（が使っているRequesモジュール）も、これらの環境変数を参照する事が上記READMEで分かります。
（Unixにおける環境変数のふるまいや設定方法は別途調べて下さい）

質問のエラーは、

> ENOTFOUND http http:80

ですから、`http`というホスト名を解決しようとして失敗してます。
つまり、

```sh
export http_proxy=http://http/
```

のような設定が(`~/.profile`などで)なされている可能性があります。
一時的に環境変数を設定してコマンドを実行するには、

```sh
http_proxy=http://example.com/ ionic start myapp
```

のようにすればよいですが、`http_proxy`などは他のプログラムも参照するのですから、
きちんと、現状を調査し、設定を変更しておく必要があります。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます！設定確認させていただきます。1点質問なんですが、gulpなどのツールでnpm installなどは普通に行えているんですが、これらの設定とionicでダウンロードするときの設定は異なるんでしょうか？ionic startをするときだけ出る症状なのですが。。

Comment: `.npmrc`を参照するのは、たぶん`npm`だけです。追記しておきました。